# SilverStripe retrieving MetaTags(param) on a DataObject as page

Tags: php, silverstripe

When using a DataObject as page, the `MetaTags(false|true)` loses its functionality. How can you make it work?

**Controller action for retrieving DataObject**

```
public function article(SS_HTTPRequest $request) {
    $article = NewsArticle::get()->find("URL", $request->param('ID'));

    if(!$article) {
        return $this->httpError(404);
    }

    return array (
        'Article' => $article,
        'Title' => $article->Title,
        'MetaDescription' => $article->MetaDescription
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MetaTags function is located in SilverStripes [sitetree class](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.4/source-class-SiteTree.html#_MetaTags).

Just copy it to your newsarticle dataobject and adjust it to fit your needs.

If you want to display more dataobjects than that one as a page, you should think about packing all the basic stuff like urlsegment, metatags, link ... in one class and than just extend this one.

There's also a module with does that [DataObject-as-Page](https://github.com/arambalakjian/DataObject-as-Page)

Comment: That was easier than thought. I copied the MetaTags function over to my DO and added this to the page controller action that handles the dataobject as page: `'MetaTags' => $article->MetaTags(false)`. I'm hardcoding the *include title* parameter here because I see no other way. Any suggestions on that? In the ideal case it would read the parameter from the function call in the ss file `$MetaTags(False)`